# Selenium Execution hangs for 3 hours on IE

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-iedriver

Selenium 3.4.0

IE 11

Windows 10

I am launching IE using Webdriver(RemoteWebDriver). But it gets stucked at http://localhost//some_random_number and doesn't moves further.Code to launch IE is :

```
    WebDriver driver = null; String errMsg = "";

    try { 
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        cap.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
        URL sURL = null;
        sURL = new URL("http://localhost:5558/wd/hub");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(sURL, cap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

Command to start HUB and IE grid is :

```
   cd "<path to seleniumjar>" && D: && javaw -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub

   cd "<path to seleniumjar and ie driver" && D: && javaw -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer_64.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=5 -port 5558
```

Also the whole selenium thread gets hanged up here for 3 hours after which following exception occurs

```
Error: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'INNOSZPC00536', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
    at com.automatics.packages.library.Web$Helper.launchIE(Web.java:2645)
    at com.automatics.packages.library.Web$Helper.access$0(Web.java:2568)
    at com.automatics.packages.library.Web.wbLaunchBrowser(Web.java:92)
    at com.automatics.packages.testScripts.google_tc.test(google_tc.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingInputStream.read(LoggingInputStream.java:87)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
    at ...
```

I want to exit in 30 seconds if browser is unreachable, how to reset this default 3 hours timeout to 30 seconds. Also what to do in case the execution is stucked at localhost page.

Comment: add lines of code which you've written

Comment: @PotnuruRavi Added Code

Comment: have you mentioned IE Driver path in your code?

Comment: Are the node and hub in the same machine? Using 'localhost' seems strange in a grid setup, use ip...

Comment: @PotnuruRavi Yes the path is same for selenium jar and ie driver, and the grid starts successfully.

Comment: @Grasshopper Requirement is to run on remote machine or localhost as and when required, By default the code runs on localhost. Works fine for Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @AnuChawla Try adding 127.0.0.1 localhost to hosts file...